# What are Double Quotes in Oracle (XMLElement)?

Tags: oracle

What type does "Foo" have in the following:

```
select XMLElement("Foo", 'Bar') from dual
```

?

Comment: Is it really that hard to look this up in the manual? Or even try it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have a "type" (i.e. it's not a number, date or character string) - it's just the label for the XML node.

The double-quotes stops Oracle from converting the label to uppercase, i.e.:

```
select XMLElement(Foo, 'Bar') from dual;

<FOO>Bar</FOO>

select XMLElement("Foo", 'Bar') from dual;

<Foo>Bar</Foo>
```